# Java Pattern with groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have this pattern:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]){11}");
```

My problem is how to get all numbers from group and sum it. 
I'm trying with this code but is isn't working:

```
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(field);
    int result = 0;

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            String number = matcher.group(i + 1);
            result += Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
```

The only group that it finds is the last group.

Comment: This is because `.matches()` only matches once per input.

Comment: and [`Matcher#groupCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()) returns the number of capturing groups in the matcher's **pattern**.

Comment: Are you trying to sum the individual single digits?!?  `"1234" = 1+2+3+4`

Comment: @Bailey S Yes, I'm trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you can use String's "substring()" instead?**

**See example below:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringOfNumbers = "AAA23211111111BBB";

    int sumOfDigits = 0;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{11})").matcher(stringOfNumbers);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String extractedNumbers = matcher.group(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < extractedNumbers.length(); i++) {
            int oneDigit = Integer.parseInt(extractedNumbers.substring(i, i + 1));
            sumOfDigits += oneDigit;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sum of digits: " + sumOfDigits); // Output: 'Sum of digits: 15'
}
```